# PHP extract a substring between two strings before a substring found

Tags: php, substring, reverse, string-matching

I have this string of escaped html code:

```
$html="
...
euro�&lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie di &lt;strong&gt;Importo Ridotto&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
                                        euro�&lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie di &lt;strong&gt;Rischio Tripartito&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
                                        euro�&lt;strong&gt;25.000,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie ai sensi del &lt;strong&gt;Dl Liquidita' 08/04/2020 art.13 lettera m)&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
...";
```

How can I extract the value between "`&lt;strong&gt`" and "`&lt;/strong&gt;`" if a substring is matched after it ( "Operazioni finanziarie", "Rischio Tripartito" ...)?
Basically if I find the substring I need to go in reverse from the position to extract the value between the two substrings.

I thought using something like:

```
$stringBefore=strstr($html,$stringToFind,true);
```

and then find the bounds of the string "between" in $stringBefore with two strpos with negative offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to get that value:

`\&lt;strong&gt;(.+?)\&lt;(?:\/strong&gt;).+(?:Operazioni finanziarie|Rischio Tripartito|etc)`

```
<?php
$html="
...
euro�&lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie di &lt;strong&gt;Importo Ridotto&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
                                        euro�&lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie di &lt;strong&gt;Rischio Tripartito&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
                                        euro�&lt;strong&gt;25.000,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie ai sensi del &lt;strong&gt;Dl Liquidita' 08/04/2020 art.13 lettera m)&lt;/strong&gt;;&lt;br/&gt;
...";
preg_match_all("/\&lt;strong&gt;(.+?)\&lt;(?:\/strong&gt;).+(Operazioni finanziarie|Rischio Tripartito|etc)/", $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => &lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie
            [1] => &lt;strong&gt;0,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie di &lt;strong&gt;Rischio Tripartito
            [2] => &lt;strong&gt;25.000,00&lt;/strong&gt;�sono relativi a Operazioni finanziarie
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0,00
            [1] => 0,00
            [2] => 25.000,00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Operazioni finanziarie
            [1] => Rischio Tripartito
            [2] => Operazioni finanziarie
        )

)
```